# How to display nodes of current level?

Tags: c++, binary-tree

Build a binary search tree from the input sequence of real numbers. Display
the values in the nodes that have the level specified by user. 
I can’t figure out what principle of finding values ​​and algorithm.
How to write a function for such an algorithm

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Node
{

  int data;
  Node *left;
  Node *right;
};
Node *root = NULL;

void InsertNode(int x, Node *leaf)
{
  Node *new_node = new Node;
  new_node->data = x;
  new_node->left = NULL;
  new_node->right = NULL;
  if (leaf == NULL)
    root = new_node;
  else

      if (x < leaf->data)

    if (leaf->left != NULL)

      InsertNode(x, leaf->left);

    else

      leaf->left = new_node;

  else

      if (x >= leaf->data)

    if (leaf->right != NULL)

      InsertNode(x, leaf->right);

    else

      leaf->right = new_node;
}



int main()
{

  int x, n = 0;
  cout << "Enter 10 numbers" << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {

    cin >> x;
    InsertNode(x, root);
  }


  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

How to display nodes of **current level** based my struct

```
struct Node
{

  int data;
  Node *left;
  Node *right;
};
Node *root = NULL;
```

Comment: Use a counter for the level. Print the node when you reach the given level. I suggest a recursive approach, something like `void print(Node *node, int level, int currentLevel = 0) {if (currentLevel == level) {cout << data; return;} print(left, level, currentLevel + 1;print(right, level, currentLevel + 1;}`

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this

```
void print_level(Node *root, int level)
{
  if (! level)
    cout << root->data;
  else
  {
    print_level(root->left, level - 1);
    print_level(root->right, level - 1);
  }
}
```

and then just call the function

```
print_level(root, 3);
```

which will print all Nodes at depth 3. (Assuming the root Node is at level 0.)